# Is it possible to have an Indicator-spesific Trait factor model within a multiple indicator second order growth model?

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, curve-fitting, latent-variable

I am running a multiple-indicator growth curve model over 7 time points.

One of my items has a large residual variance and seems to covary very well among themselves.
Thus, I assumed that it has a state-like nature that is invariant over time so I
modeled it as a factor on its own.
So the path diagram would be kind of like this model below where there are no M2 and M3.
(only one of my indicators have this property)
[image]

In that case,

1. Is it alright to have the item-specific factor (e.g. one of the M factors in this diagram) correlate with the second-order growth factors (e.g. α and β in the diagram)?
2. Are there other things to be aware of except not letting the item-specific factor correlate with the first-order factors (e.g. η1-3 in the diagram)
   (the item that create the item-specific factor is partially invariant (scalar).
   It has two freed intercepts out of the seven. I don't know if this becomes a problem but I thought it was something worth noting.)

If there are any applications like this it would be very helpful if someone could point me to it.

Thank everyone in advance who would give me advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are not entirely clear to me. If the item in question is strongly correlated with itself over time, this would speak against the idea of it being state-like. Rather, it would indicate high stability (consistency) of individual differences across time.

If you included a method factor only for the one item in question (but not for the other two), that would imply that the growth factors are defined by the remaining two items and that those two items are homogeneous except for differences in scaling (and error variance). The question is whether that's realistic.

A more realistic model would be one in which only one item is selected as reference (not two). This may be, for example, your special item for which you find high cosistency. For the reference item, no method factor is included (M - 1 approach; Eid, Schneider, & Schwenkmezger, 1999). In the M - 1 approach, the method factors are residual factors that are not allowed to correlate with either the first-order factors or the growth factors. But the method factors could be correlated with other method factors. In either case (one or two method factors), the method factor(s) should not be allowed to correlate with the growth factors.

Another option would be a growth model with indicator-specific growth factors (see Bishop, Geiser, & Cole, 2015). That model may be of interest to you if you suspect that your items reflect partially distinct growth processes. It is simpler in some ways because it does not require the inclusion of method factors. It also allows all items to have their own (indicator-specific) intercept and slope factors.

Bishop, J., Geiser, C., & Cole, D. A. (2015). Modeling growth with multiple indicators: A comparison of three approaches. Psychological Methods, 20, 43-62.

Eid, M., Schneider, C., & Schwenkmezger, P. (1999). Do you feel better or worse? The validity of perceived deviations of mood states from mood traits. European Journal of Personality, 13, 283–306.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and advice!

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and advice! The item with large residual variance overtime that covary very well among themselves I meant to say had a trait like nature and thought it may have been the case that it will form a latent trait factor on its own. With your advice I understand that a model with indicator specific growth factor might be close to what I am looking for. I will definitely find your article very inspiring. Thank you so much again!